# c# handling keypresses

Tags: c#

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9')
        if (e.KeyChar != '\b')
            e.Handled = true;

}
```

i am not understanding how this code is not allowing anything except backspace and numbers.

1. the first if statement is saying if it is not 0 - 9 then dont do anything?
2. the second one is saying if it's not backspace dont do anything?
3. what does `e.Handled=True` do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first `if` statement is basically saying if it *is* a digit, allow it to proceed as normal - otherwise go into the second `if` statement.

The second `if` statement is saying that if it's also not backspace, allow it to proceed as normal - otherwise go onto the assignment statement.

`e.Handled = true;` indicates that the event handler has already processed the event and dealt with it, so it doesn't need to be processed any further. In other words, please don't take any further action.

Here's an alternative way of writing the same body:

```
bool isDigit = e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9';
bool isBackspace = e.KeyChar == '\b';

// If we get anything other than a digit or backspace, tell the rest of
// the event processing logic to ignore this event
if (!isDigit && !isBackspace)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I really like the way you refactored the code because it's very easy to understand the logic once you get to the `if` statement.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I red your answer and I need to ask you something, I had event attached to my TextBox which is being triggered when I hit sign "+", and that event basicaly 'unlocked' my TextBox which was disabled, and before i wrote e.Handled=true; everytime I wanted to unlock TextBox with "+" key, that key also appeared in that TextBox, and when I added e.Handled=true; "+" sign stopped to appear in my TextBox which I am unlocking by pressing that sign, how come ? Could you please explain me that I really appreciate your words. Or if you want I can open new qeustion for that and leave link here..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: You should definitely ask a new question with a [mcve]. But basically, if you set `e.Handled` to `true`, that means you've already handled the event, so the `TextBox` *won't* acknowledge the keypress.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2: It's actually the other way around. This is saying that "if the key is not 0-9, then check if it is backspace. If it is not backspace, then e.Handled is true."

3: When e.Handled is set to true the control, parent form, and whatever other thing listening to capture the key press will NOT do anything. e.Handled basically says, "It is taken care of, no one else worry about it."

Answer (score 1):

What this code is doing is setting `e.Handled=true` when the character is

- Not a number character
- And not the backspace character